# django i18n translation not working on nginx but works on runserver

Tags: django, internationalization, translation

It took me a while to get translation working on my local development server (runserver) and then after I deployed to nginx server(another server) and translation stopped working again. I cannot figure out what's missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it working, somehow ubuntu doesn't like the folder name 'zh_cn' in locale directory, instead, it likes zh_CN.

Answer (score 2):

As it is mentioned in i18n [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/), Django accepts a `Accept-Language` header. Probably nginx does not pass that header to Django so you have to pass it manually. Just add the `proxy_pass_header` as outlined below to your nginx config.

```
location / {
    proxy_pass ...
    proxy_pass_header "Accept-Language";
}
```

Comment: hmm that didn't work, the browser actually changed fonts and one of the string actually changed to desired translation but not all strings were translated like in development server.